# Read csv file in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read a .csv file in R. 
My file looks like this-

```
A,B,C,D,E

1,2,3,4,5

6,7,8,9,10

.

.

.
```

number of rows.

All are strings. First line is the header.

I am trying to read the file using-

```
mydata=read.csv("devices.csv",sep=",",header = TRUE)
```

But mydata is assigned X observations of 1 variable. Where  X is number of rows. The whole row becomes a single column.
But I want every header field in different column. I am not able to understand the problem.

Comment: Check to see that your csv file isnt missing a comma anywhere, especially in the row containing the column names.

Comment: Can you try `read.table(text=gsub('"', '', readLines('devices.csv')), sep=",", header=TRUE)`

Comment: It is not doing so. I have no idea why os it so. I have read a number of other answers but no one works.

Comment: @akrun I did but it doesn't work for me till now.

Comment: Yes. gsub is working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If there are quotes (`"`), by using the code in the OP's post

```
str(read.csv("devices.csv",sep=",",header = TRUE))
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ A.B.C.D.E: Factor w/ 2 levels "1,2,3,4,5","6,7,8,9,10": 1 2
```

We could remove the `"` with `gsub` after reading the data with `readLines` and then use `read.table`

```
read.csv(text=gsub('"', '', readLines('devices.csv')), sep=",", header=TRUE)
#  A B C D  E
#1 1 2 3 4  5
#2 6 7 8 9 10
```

Another option if we are using `linux` would be to remove quotes with `awk` and pipe with `read.csv`

```
  read.csv(pipe("awk  'gsub(/\"/,\"\",$1)' devices.csv")) 
  #  A B C D  E
  #1 1 2 3 4  5
  #2 6 7 8 9 10
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 fread("awk  'gsub(/\"/,\"\",$1)' devices.csv") 
 #   A B C D  E
 #1: 1 2 3 4  5
 #2: 6 7 8 9 10
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("A,B,C,D,E", "1,2,3,4,5", "6,7,8,9,10")
write.table(v1, file='devices.csv', row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code which you've written should work unless your csv file is corrupted.
***Check giving absolute path of devices.csv***

To test: `data[1]` will give you column 1 results

Or, You can try it this way too

```
data = read.table(text=gsub('"', '', readLines('//fullpath to devices.csv//')), sep=",", header=TRUE)
```

Good Luck!